# Is there a spreadsheet function, than means same formula as a specified cell?

Tags: google-sheets

In google sheets. I wish to have the same function in several cells. I could copy the function to all the other cells (this will work). However if I want to change the function, then I need to copy it again.

Is there a way to say "this cell should have the same function (not value), as this other cell"? But not by copying the function.

## An explanation

- We can put a cell reference into a cell, to copy the value. (value reference)
- We can copy the formula from one cell to another (this auto adjusts cell references). However if we change the formula, we have to change it in every cell. (formula copy)
- I am looking for a ways to put a reference to the formula into cells. (formula reference)

e.g.

A1 has `=b1*c1`
and
A2 has `=call(a1)`, this function `call`, that I do not know if it exists, evaluates a reference to the formula in `a1`, not the value in `a1`. Therefore it would be as if I had copied the formula from a1. However if I were to change the formula in `a1` then the effect of this formula in a2 would change, as if a had re-copied (if I had originally made a copy then it would not change).

## How it will be used

- I have a formula in cell `A1`.
- I want to copy the formula from `A1` to the rest of column `A`. However I know that this formula will change many times (if I copy it, I will have to re-copy every time I change the formula).
- Therefore I want to put a formula in the rest of column `A`, that is equivalent in behaviour as copying `A1`, but the behaviour will change tracking changes in the formula in `A1`.

Comment: With respect, your question is somewhat vague and difficult to visualise. Would you please give an example of the function you have in mind, and  what you mean by _a way to say "this cell should have the same function (not value), as this other cell"? But not by copying the function._

_

Comment: Thanks. Kind of like trying to solve a riddle, but I'll keep thinking. Two quick comments: 1-does this topic [Use Text in cell as formula in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/145809/196152); offer any interest? It's a very recent question but involved a text reference to a formula. 2-Never assume: have you considered the use of absolute and/or partial absolute cell references. This would still enable a formula to be copied but retain it's focus on the original cells.

Comment: @Tedinoz I have done some more clarification.

Comment: You mention a "Value reference" (such as `=A1` or `=$A$1`) but this is actually consequential on the formula in Cell A1. You also mention a "formula reference" but I suggest that there is no difference between this and a "value reference". In any event, the style that you use (`=call(a1)`) suggests a custom function, and custom functions can't be used to set cell formulas. On the other hand, you could write a function to copy the formula from one cell to another, but you'd have to run this manually.

Answer (score 0):

You want a way for a formula entered in Cell A1 can be applied to the rows in Column A without needing to edit multiple cells.

`ARRAYFORMULA` [(Doc ref)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) offers this functionality. In fact it enables far more sophisticated and complex calculations, and there are many examples of precedents on webapps and StackOverflow (and other websites).

Here is an example of `Arrayformula` where it is simply multiplying two cell values:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B)*LEN(C2:C), B2:B * C2:C,))`

---

**Example**

[image]

---

Hat tip: [Arrayformula - multiply only if the both columns have a value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40411099/1330560)