# Use Text in cell as formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am working on a way of building out a formula rather than a bunch of if/then statements.  Is there a way I can convert the text from one cell and use that text as the formula of another?

Example:

```
A1 = 1
A2 = 2
```

B1's formula reads `=A1+A2`, resulting in the value of 3 in cell B1

In C1, if I have the text value of `A1+A2`, is there a way in cell D1 I can reference the text of C1 to display the value of 3?

I tried `="=" & indirect(C1)` and  `=indirect("=" & C1)` but both fail.

Comment: Have you read [Convert a text string to a formula in a spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35022815/1330560)? Four years old, which is a long time, but off the top of my head, I can't think of a better solution. (which possibly means there IS a better solution) ;-)

Comment: First time seeing it.   I am sure I am not using the correct search terms.  That one from what i can see is using google scrip to make it work.  So i am guessing that I cant do what i want in a formula only then?

Comment: Is the formula as predictable as in your example scenario?

Comment: @Tedinoz The answer you gave worked best.  I am using that solution.

Comment: @Tedinoz Can you post it up as an answer so i can mark it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula in cell D1:

`=(indirect(left(C1,find("+",C1)-1)))+(indirect(right(C1,len(C1)-find("+",C1))))`

The logic is explained in the screenshot

---

**Sample**

[image: Sample]

---

| Sequence | Task | Value | Formula | Consolidated formula |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| #1 | find "+" | 3 | =find("+",C1) |  |
| #2 | left of "+" | A1 | =left(C1,C5-1) | =left(C1,find("+",C1)-1) |
| #3 | overall length | 5 | =len(C1) |  |
| #4 | right of + | A2 | =right(C1,C7-C5) | =right(C1,len(C1)-find("+",C1)) |
| #5 | value left | 1 | =indirect(C6) | =indirect(left(C1,find("+",C1)-1)) |
| #6 | value right | 2 | =indirect(C8) | =indirect(right(C1,len(C1)-find("+",C1))) |
| #7 | sum | 3 | =C9+C10 | =(indirect(left(C1,find("+",C1)-1)))+(indirect(right(C1,len(C1)-find("+",C1)))) |

---

Comment: While an image might be helpful, text and formulas are better to be shown using text. Besides regular readability, think of people using small screens and screen readers.

Comment: @Rubén Thank you for the wake-up call; and very easy to do using [tablesgenerator.com](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).